# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[4, 32, 6, 7] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement such CNN.

[image]

This is my implementation:

```
class Net(BaseFeaturesExtractor):
    def __init__(self, observation_space: gym.spaces.Box, features_dim: int = 256):
        super(Net, self).__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
        n_input_channels = observation_space.shape[0]
        print("Observation space shape:"+str(observation_space.shape))
        print("Number of channels:" + str(n_input_channels))
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=128,out_features=64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(in_features=64,out_features=7),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, observations: th.Tensor) -> th.Tensor:
        print("Observation shape:"+str(observations[0].shape))
        return self.cnn(observations)
```

When I tried to run the code which uses this CNN, I am getting following log:

```
    Observation space shape:(3, 6, 7) 
    Number of channels:3 
    Observation shape:torch.Size([3, 6, 7]) 
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/joe/Documents/JUPYTER/ConnectX/training3.py", line 250, in <module>
        learner.learn(total_timesteps=iterations, callback=eval_callback)
...
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 3, 3, 3], expected input[4, 32, 6, 7] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead
```

What is the problem here? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_channels` of a `conv` layer should be equal to `out_channels` of the previous layer. In your case, `in_channels` of the 2nd and 3rd `conv` layers don't have the correct values. They should be like below,

```
    self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(n_input_channels, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(),
        ...
    )
```

Also, you should check `in_features` of the 1st `Linear` layer. It depends on the input shape and should be equal to `last_conv_out_channels * last_conv_output_height * last_conv_output_width`.

For example, for an `input=torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256)` last `conv` layer's output shape would be `([1, 32, 64, 64])`, in that case the 1st `Linear` layer should be,

```
nn.Linear(in_features=32*64*64,out_features=64)
```

**---- Update after the comment:**

Output shape of a `conv` layer is calculated through the formula [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) (see under "Shape:" section). Using `input = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256)` as input to the network, here are outputs of each `conv` layer (I skipped the `ReLU`s since they don't change the shape),

```
conv1: (1, 3, 256, 256) -> (1, 32, 256, 256)
conv2: (1, 32, 256, 256) -> (1, 32, 128, 128)
conv3: (1, 32, 128, 128) -> (1, 32, 64, 64)
```

So how did `last_conv_output_height` and `last_conv_output_width` became 64 ? The last `conv` layer is defined as follows,

```
nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
```

Data is processed as `(num_samples, num_channels, height​, width​)` in PyTorch and the default value for `dilation` is stated as 1 in the [conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) doc. So, for the last `conv` layer, `H_in` is 128, `padding[0]` is 1, `dilation[0]` is 1, `kernel_size[0]` is 3 and `stride[0]` is 2. Therefore, height of its output becomes,

```
H_out = ⌊(128 + 2 * 1 - 1 * (3 - 1) - 1) / 2⌋ + 1
H_out = 64
```

Since square-size kernels and equal-size stride, padding and dilation are used, `W_out` also becomes `64` for the last `conv` layer.

I think the easiest way to compute `in_features` for the 1st `Linear` layer would be run the model for the desired size input until that layer. An example for your architecture,

```
inp = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256)
arch = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
)
outp = arch(inp)
print('outp.shape:', outp.shape)
```

This prints,

```
outp.shape: torch.Size([1, 32, 64, 64])
```

Finally, `last_conv_out_channels` is `out_channels` of the last `conv` layer. The last `conv` layer in your architecture is `nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)`. Here `out_channels` is the 2nd parameter, so `last_conv_out_channels` is 32.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Now I am getting this error: RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (4x7 and 256x64). How can I know last_conv_out_channels, last_conv_output_height, last_conv_output_width?

Comment: @JoeRakhimov Sorry for not making it clear, I've updated my answer.